# Call variable when inside double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
CRED_DATA = 'randomcred'
payload = "{\n  \"password\": \"CRED_DATA\" ,\n  \"username\": \"dom\\\\user\"\n}"
print(payload)
```

Output:

```
{
  "password": "CRED_DATA" ,
  "username": "dom\\user"
}
```

I tried double quotes, single quotes, { [ etc cannot figure it out . Is there a way to call the variable when inside the dict that is double quoted?

Comment: what variable you want to call?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to get the CRED_DATA variable to be recognized inside the payload declaration. I need the value of CRED_DATA to be passed, not the actual string CRED_DATA

Comment: You don't have a "double-quoted dict"; you have a hand-crafted JSON value that can't easily be used the way you want it to be used.

Comment: @chepner , so the solution is to build a different json value to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [F-Strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) in Python:

```
CRED_DATA = 'randomcred'
payload = F"{{\n  \"password\": \"{CRED_DATA}\" ,\n  \"username\": \"dom\\\\user\"\n}}"
print(payload)
```

Output:

```
{
  "password": "randomcred" ,
  "username": "dom\\user"
}
```

However, depending on the value of `CRED_DATA`, this is not guaranteed to produce valid JSON (Thanks to @chepner). You can also use `dict` and `json.dumps()` in Python as already mentioned in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60211360/5735010).

Comment: Depending on the value of `CRED_DATA`, this is not guaranteed to produce valid JSON.

Comment: I have added your remark in my answer. However, I wanted to show another way of doing the same thing to the OP. I have linked your answer as well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Generate the JSON properly, using a `dict` and `json.dump`.

```
CRED_DATA = 'randomcred'
payload = {'password': CRED_DATA, 'username': r'dom\user'}
print(json.dumps(payload))
```

If you are getting the JSON value from somewhere else, decode it first, update the resulting `dict`, and then dump it again.

```
payload = json.loads(payload)
payload['password'] = CRED_DATA
payload = json.dumps(payload)
```

Comment: For some dumb reason the api requires everything to be quoted, I dont really understand why that is just how it seems to work.Ill give this a shot

Comment: No, the API requires valid JSON, from all appearances. You don't work directly with JSON; you work with the data structures that it represents. JSON is an interchange format.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this?

`CRED_DATA = 'randomcred'
payload = "password:",CRED_DATA
payload2 = ("\n \"username\": \"dom\\\\user\"\n}")
print(payload)
print(payload2)`

Answer (score 0):

You payload variable is not a dictionary, it is a string. I suppose you want to sort of serialize iot for sending over the network or something - it would help if you elaborated your intent.

In any case:
If you want python to resolve the variable in your string, try something like:

```
payload = "{\n  \"password\": \"" + CRED_DATA + "\" ,\n  \"username\": \"dom\\\\user\"\n}"
```

...But I personally think it would be better to use a dictionary, and json.dumps to achieve this:

```
import json

CRED_DATA = 'randomcred'

payload = {
    "password": CRED_DATA,
    "username": "dom user"
}

print(json.dumps(payload, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Again. Depending on your use case which is not clear from the question.